# Why Codeigniter3.0.4 generate four of session files when I disable cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to used CI3.0.4 for testing with Cookies if client disabled their Cookies and I will never let they come to web pages.
But when I try to disabled cookie CI will generated 4 of session files with another 3 is zero size;

And another when my session was expired CI will generate another file by keep old session files so this is good idea so if I used this website more than 2 or 3 years I will got more files in my website both in Database too.

[image]